# How would you solve this case where you're trying to debounce events when scrolling on a gridview in WPF? Need tips for student practice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridview

I will need some kind of debounce event functionality, but I have a feeling I need to run the first object event it hit on (in cases where I just click arrow once, and it jump down one object), and everyone between the first and the last will be bounced off, and the last will be invoked (in cases where I finally stop scrolling down with the arrow.)
How would you solve this?

```
    private DateTime lastEvent = DateTime.Now;
    private readonly TimeSpan EventDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    private async Task SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - lastEvent > EventDelay)
        {
           // DO STUFF
        }

        lastEvent = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack Overflow is not really a place to ask and answer hypothetical questions, but rather to look for answers of a concrete problem

Comment: It sounds like [data virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981040/1997232) to me.

Comment: With that being said, I would use some sort of countdown. Say the user presses arrow down, that would trigger the event, but before actually executing anything I'd wait for something like ~500ms, and if the user presses arrow down again within that timeframe the countdown would restart . You could then implement something that would instantly execute the event on the first press, so when the timer isn't counting down

Comment: @MindSwipe I tried something like this, I've updated the thread.
Possible if you could provide a code example?

Comment: Are you using the MVVM design pattern or code behind for this event?

Comment: I'm using MVVM, so I don't have any code behind file for the view.xaml files

Answer (score 1):

I use the [debounce Operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) from Rx.NET to solve the this kind of issues. From the docs:

> Debounce - only emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item

Note: the debounce operator is called `Throttle` in the .NET Version. The nuget package you need to add is called `System.Reactive`

You can create an Observable object from the `SelectionChanged` event of your ListView/GridView. Here is a small example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView.ItemsSource = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

        var selectionChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern
            <SelectionChangedEventHandler, SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
                h => ListView.SelectionChanged += h,
                h => ListView.SelectionChanged -= h);

        var debouncedObservable = selectionChangedObservable
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher();

        debouncedObservable.Subscribe(SelectionChangedDebounced);
    }

    private void SelectionChangedDebounced(EventPattern<SelectionChangedEventArgs> ep)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item {ListView.SelectedItem} selected");
    }
}
```

Thats the XAML part:

```
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" Margin="10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

With this code, every following SelectionChanged event is ignored until there was no event for 1 second. After one second, the `SelectionChangedDebounced(...)` method is called for the last item that has been selected.

**Update: Using Throttle in your ViewModel**

You can use this approach with any event. But your event handler delegate cannot have a return type. Be careful: When you call `OnSelection?.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` you dont await any of the returned Tasks! This can lead to all sorts of problems.

I think the best way would be to change the delegate type of your event handler from `AsyncHandler` to `EventHandler`. Then you can use `Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => OnSelection += h, h => OnSelection -= h)...` in your viewmodel, just like the example above shows. If you cant change the delegate type (maybe its from an external dependency), you could try using a Subject as a proxy:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly Subject<Unit> _selectionChangedSubject;
    private string _selectedItem;

    // Note: Event delegates should not return values! -> use void instead of Task.
    public delegate Task AsyncHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    
    public event AsyncHandler OnSelection;

    public List<string> Items => new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { _selectedItem = value; RaiseEvent();  }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _selectionChangedSubject = new Subject<Unit>();
        _selectionChangedSubject
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Subscribe(OnSelectionChangedDebounced);
        OnSelection += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private Task OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _selectionChangedSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChangedDebounced(Unit _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item selected: {SelectedItem}");
    }

    private void RaiseEvent()
    {
        // !! This does not await any of the returned Tasks!
        OnSelection?.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... 
I'm doing the MVVM approach, is it possible to put this in the viewmodel instead?
@TobiasHoefer

Comment: My event is also of this type: How would it be if I adapt it to work with this?       

 public delegate Task AsyncHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
        public event AsyncHandler OnSelectionChanged;

Comment: I updated the thread, I cannot use ListView.SelectionChanged :/

Comment: Yes you can use the code in your viewmodel. The problem is the delegate type of your event. Event delegates should not have a return type. You would need to update your event delagate from 'Task AsyncHandler(object, EventArgs)' to 'void AsyncHandler(object EventArgs)'. But then of course, its just the simple 'EventHandler' delegate. I will add a ViewModel example to my answer.

Comment: I think I will change to EventHandler instead then.
Would you mind change your version to a EventHandler one? That fixes the non awaiting dynamic invoke?

Comment: Could you explain my why I have to do Task.CompletedTask? Because I think I never did it in any of my async task methods...

Comment: maybe you could show me how you would have done it to make it more correct, as I understood, my approach is not the best, as I'm using this asyncHandler

Comment: what is the idea of using += -= part of the assignment of h do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The simple pattern to use is to add a task.delay in your event and ignore any old ones until you run out of new ones.

You've comnplicated this in your basic design because you don't pass what is selected and hence what to work with into your handler. There is no difference between your events. They're all just "something happened" and then another "something happened".

If you consider a mouse move debounce, this may be clearer:

```
    private Point lastPosition = new Point();
    private async void ShaperCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(ShaperCanvas);
        if (lastPosition == pt)
        {
```

Here we can see if the user stopped moving the mouse.

In your code it seems you will want a LastSelectedItem instead.
So your logic will be stash what's selected locally.
Wait a bit.
See if what is selected is different from what you started with.
If it is different then there's another event happened so exit.

You may also want an isbusy flag so nothing can happen whilst one of these is being processed.

Something like:

```
private async Task SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var LastSelectedItem = CurrentSelectedItem;
    await Task.Delay(200);
    if(CurrentSelectedItem != LastSelectedItem)
    { 
         resume;
    }

    // DO STUFF
```